# Fetching impersonated user list using powershell command

Tags: powershell, office365

I am trying to fetch the list of the **impersonated** **users** of Office365 using powershell command. I tried with various commands to get the impersonated users list but unable to get the correct command. Please help.

Thanks;
Mayuresh.